# Stuck on "Connecting to WiFi" screen while provisioning Android Lollipop device

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, device-owner

I am trying to auto connect with WiFi when provisioning Android Lollipop device using below NFC tags:

```
p.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID, "-----");
p.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_PASSWORD, "----");
```

It seems it is getting connected with WiFi but stuck on `Connecting to Wi-fi...` Screen and it is not finishing with provisioning process.

Can anybody guide me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to surround SSID with double quotes :
p.setProperty(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_WIFI_SSID, "\"my SSI\"");

Comment: Can confirm that this works - should probably be accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

To make it work I had to set the also the flag `android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_WIFI_SECURITY_TYPE`.

Specify only the two `EXTRA` for SSID and PASSWORD as stated in the docs isn't enough. Probably the default security type remains `NONE`.

Comment: Thank you, was breaking my head over this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's broken in L MR0 (Android 5.0).

However, it's my experience that it has been fixed in L MR1 (Android 5.1).

It works for us now (I work at Sony Mobile).

The fix went into ManagedProvisioning git:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ManagedProvisioning/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several things without success. The feature seems broken.

You should probably enter the WiFi info manually.